# Issue with Maven Build Profiles

Tags: java, maven

I as working in a maven project which is used to run both UI and API tests. So as a result the POM file contains several dependencies related to UI automation and api automation and is unmanageable. Now we are looking into modularising the project into manageable components and using maven profiles is the approach we are going to go ahead with.

So I have created two profiles as UI and API and put all ui related dependencies under UI profile and API related ones under API profiles. dependencies used commonly are defined under the dependencies tag in the root pom file.

So the issue is - when i run 'mvn clean install -P UI' and run the maven profile, test classes related to API tests are giving an error->  'package io.restassured.http does not exist'. (dependency related to rest assured is inside API profile)

Is it possible to modularize the POM file as I have done here ? or have i made any mistake ?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

4.0.0

```
<groupId>org.example</groupId>
<artifactId>TestProfile</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.19.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <testFailureIgnore>true</testFailureIgnore>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>

<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>UI</id>
        <activation>
            <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
        </activation>

        <dependencies>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
                <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
                <version>4.18.1</version>
            </dependency>

            <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.maven.plugins/maven-compiler-plugin -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.12.1</version>
            </dependency>

            <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.github.bonigarcia/webdrivermanager -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>io.github.bonigarcia</groupId>
                <artifactId>webdrivermanager</artifactId>
                <version>5.7.0</version>
            </dependency>

        </dependencies>
    </profile>

    <profile>
        <id>API</id>
        <activation>
            <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
        </activation>
        <dependencies>

            <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.rest-assured/rest-assured -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>io.rest-assured</groupId>
                <artifactId>rest-assured</artifactId>
                <version>5.4.0</version>
            </dependency>

            <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.json/json -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.json</groupId>
                <artifactId>json</artifactId>
                <version>20240303</version>
            </dependency>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.googlecode.json-simple</groupId>
                <artifactId>json-simple</artifactId>
                <version>1.1.1</version>
            </dependency>

            <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hamcrest/hamcrest -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.hamcrest</groupId>
                <artifactId>hamcrest</artifactId>
                <version>2.2</version>
                <scope>test</scope>
            </dependency>

        </dependencies>
    </profile>

</profiles>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
        <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
        <version>7.9.0</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.maven.plugins/maven-compiler-plugin -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.12.1</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<properties>
    <maven.compiler.source>11</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>11</maven.compiler.target>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
</properties>
```

Comment: Since UI and API classes are in the same source folder, Maven will try to compile them together. If you have added just the dependencies for one (say API) in the build through the selected profile (`-P API`), compilation of the other classes (the UI) will naturally fail because their dependencies are missing. The way to go is Maven modules: split the UI and API tests into 2 separate Maven modules, each with their respective dependencies.

Comment: You abuse profiles for somethings they are not intended to. Read https://www.sonatype.com/maven-complete-reference/build-profiles to learn about profiles. As @Nikos said, modules aka multi-module-builds is what you are looking for.

Comment: Upgrade the used plugins verison like maven-surefire-plugin (currently 3.2.5) (ref: https://maven.apache.org/plugins/) also do not use profile to use different dependencies... those dependencies are test deps ... so you should define their scope accordingly ..also as already mentioned two different things.. Make two separate modules of it... and parent pom (aka multi module build) etc..Having a plugin (maven-compiler-plugin) as a dependency is completely wrong...

Comment: Thank you very much NikosParaskevopoulos, Martin Höller, khmarbaise for the answers. I was anyway considering maven modules and profiles are the options here, but i understand now that Profile is not an option. Will continue to work on Maven Modules and Thank you again for the answers